# Quercus (PHP on Google App Engine) is_file is_dir not Working

Tags: php, google-app-engine, quercus

I have a PHP application running on Google App Engine, who has the ability to run [PHP on GAE via Quercus](http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/run-php-on-the-google-app-engine/). However, I notice that my scripts choke on GAE when they run an is_dir() or is_file() function. These functions work just fine on a "regular" PHP server.

According to the link I gave above above, I have configured my application correctly, as all else works just fine. What could be the cause of this sticking point? Is it a GAE configuration, or does Quercus not support these functions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Choke" must be a technical term I'm not familiar with. Have you considered telling us what _actually_ happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local disk limitations are part of the Google App Engine restrictions, see [Why can't I read from this file?](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#readfile)

> It is possible to read from a file which is uploaded as part of your application provided that it is in the following locations:
>
> - war/WEB-INF
> - in a location matching the  pattern in appengine-web.xml (which by default includes everything)